# Connect2 and Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to get connect and socket.io to work together nicely and simply. I have the following code on server side:

```
var connect = require('connect'),
    io = require('socket.io');

var app = connect().use(connect.logger('dev'));
var sio = io.listen(app);

app.listen(8000);
```

when I open http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js  I get the error:

```
Cannot GET /socket.io/socket.io.js
```

And Socket.IO doesn't work, I'm trying copy file and load from another location, but socket.io requests do not reach the server

Comment: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/500#issuecomment-4620773

Comment: You should post this as an answer to your question, and accept it, for future reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[SOLUTION](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/500#issuecomment-4620773)

if anyone comes to this issue, you need to wrap the connect/express app in a node http.Server. The app.listen() method is a convenience method for this and returns the server:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var app = connect();
var server = app.listen(3000);
io.listen(server);
```

or the following is equivalent:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var http = require('http');
var app = connect();
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3000);
io.listen(server);
```